Исправить ошибку No such file or directory
Решил сделать приложение с помощью библиотеки flet, установил ее, но код выдает ошибку:
/home/runner/.flet/bin/flet-0.22.1/flet/flet: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Подскажите, как эту ошибку можно исправить?
Код пишу в Replit

gui библиотеки не будут работать в онлайн интерпретаторах. Устанавливаете python локально, устанавливаете на него flet, и работаете.

Хорошо. Благодарю за помощь

Хотя можно попробовать запускать в веб режиме: https://flet.dev/docs/publish/web/dynamic-website#running-the-app-locally
